# Using Regula-Falsi to determine the solution to a non-linear system

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, rootfinding

Apologies, for this isn't a field or subject I know much about.

Regula Falsi (I believe some may know this as "double false position" or something like this) can be used trivially, of course, to determine the root of some arbitrary non-linear equation (forgoing some special cases, other details...). How might Regula Falsi be applied to the solution of a non-linear *system*, provided we can assume such a solution exists?

It seems like such a simple thing, and I know that it *can* and *has* been done, yet I cannot find any literature on this, nor can I quite ascertain how one might go about doing this nor why it works.